# How to prevent file location from showing?

Tags: php, filesystems, location, storage

I am allowing users to upload documents to the server.  However, i don't want them to obviously see where the files are being stored.  What can i do that will allow them to still get the file but without seeing the file location.

Comment: Why would they see where the files are being stored?

Comment: In order to serve them the documents there would be a link to download, right?

Comment: Are talking about uploading (a client sending files to the server), or downloading (a client pulling files from the server)?

Comment: users upload documents and then they can download the documents they have uploaded.

Comment: Ah, I see...  Have a look at this: [Prevent Directory browsing and file retrieval without querystring token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719815/prevent-directory-browsing-and-file-retrieval-without-querystring-token)

Comment: @Mike -- good comment and +1 for adding it as a comment instead of an answer since it is an answer already. See this boys and girls proper usage of comments vs answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a PHP query to accomplish this, lets say you use the following URL:

```
http://mysite.com/files.php?file=xyz.pdf
```

In files.php you can check the get variable file and have a hard coded function that retrieves the file. You can do this many ways one by using headers to force a download or read the file into a var and print it's contents to the page. For say like a pdf reading the file and printing it to the page is the same as linking it to the file.

warning though: like with using headers do not print anything to the page except the file. I also recommend declairing you headers still if you read the file and print it so that the end user will not get the gobbly goop that is the source of the file i.e. jpg or pdf.

Oh no, I forgot a header warning, I have been running into a header problem ever since Adobe made the ISO for PDF's open source, depending on the application that produced the PDF and the browser from which the user is uploading the PDF from, the header will be anything from:

```
'application/pdf', 'application/x-download','application/octet-stream','application/octet','binary/octet-stream'
```

so be careful hard coding the upload section to a header type, I know this question is about downloads but i just thought i would throw that in there. Also using headers for downloads doesn't matter I would simply use the standard application/pdf there.

Comment: +1 It's not just about speed of typing.  It's about providing a good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't it be idea to actually have an id so once the person goes to page.php?id=idjfkldj a pop will open asking them to open/save?

Comment: @KPO yes but then you would have to create a DB and store the ID and filename in a table. It would just add a bit more work and a bit more security. so it is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways todo this but i prefer using .htaccess

So my link would look like `http://example.com/files/filename.zip`
extra parameters within the url could be used a username or password like:

```
 http://example.com/files/bob/filename.zip

 http://example.com/files/18d52c/filename.zip
```

Then thos could be checked against a database to see if user is allowed to download that specific file, much like you would use for instant downloads after payment.. but a basic method would be like so:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ serve.php?file=$1
```

**serve.php**

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    $file=basename($_GET['file']);
    //Protect the index.php && serve.php
    if(basename($_GET['file'])=='index.php' || basename($_GET['file'])=='serve.php'){
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");die();
    }
    $downloadFolder="original_location/";
    if(file_exists($downloadFolder.$file)){

        $fsize = filesize($downloadFolder.$file);
        $ctype=finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $downloadFolder.$file);

        if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        if(strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")==false) {
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        }else{
            header("Content-Type: $ctype");
        }
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile('original_location/'.$file);
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
    die();
 }
 header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

**original_location/index.php**

```
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
```

Comment: You could replace the entire mime-type business with http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php...

Comment: Thanks ive added your suggestion.

Comment: +1 beautiful implementation there Lawrence, it covers all the bases and error scenarios. I am almost ashamed of my answer now, I mean I basically told him the same thing but your code covers all the bases and if you don't mind I would like to add it to my snippet library, with a reference to you of course.

Comment: absolutely, half the questions I answer are storage for little snippets ;p

Answer (score 1):

Store it using some random unique ID that you can map to the real file, then serve it using a script that does [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) on the actual file.

The http://php.net/readfile docs also have an example on how to force it being a download.

Comment: Really? Same answer and posted within seconds of mine but already has a up vote? oh well have to type faster i guess good job there Tino.

Comment: I wasn't trying to get in a fast one. I just posted what I thought was enough information for him to investigate further and find a scheme that would work.

Comment: oh no man i was just saying bad luck for me, no big deal really it was all in a joking manner i wasn't upset or anything.